# Why does my use of Java generics extends not work?

Tags: java

This code doesn't compile and I have a hard time understanding why:

```
private final Map<String, ValueWriter<? extends Value>> valueWriters = new HashMap<>();

public void write(CompositeValue value) throws IOException {
    for (Entry<String, ValueWriter<? extends Value>> writer : valueWriters.entrySet()) {
        Value v = value.getValue().get(writer.getKey());
        ValueWriter<? extends Value> valueWriter = writer.getValue();
        valueWriter.write(v);
    }
}
```

This gives me the following compilation error at `valueWriter.write(v)`:

```
incompatible types: Value cannot be converted to capture#1 of ? extends Value
```

Where ValueWriter is implemented as follows:

```
public interface ValueWriter<T extends Value> {
    void write(T value) throws IOException;
    void delete(Key key) throws IOException;
}
```

Basically, I would expect `valueWriter` to accept any class implementing the interface Value. Why doesn't this work, and how can I implement it so that it does?

Minimal reproducible example:

```
public class Main {
    private ValueWriter<? extends Value> writer;

    public void write(Value v) {
        writer.write(v);
    }
    
    interface Value {
        
    }
    interface ValueWriter<T extends Value> {
        void write(T v);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the exact error message you get.

Comment: "*doesn't compile*" like there is an error, or what? If you got an error, please include the error message in question - helpful information (most often)

Comment: Looks like you're trying to instantiate a `ValueWriter`, which you can't do because it's an interface, not a class.

Comment: Edited to add the exact error message

Comment: Your type says the writer need only accept some unknown subtype of `Value`, so how do you know that the value you're giving it is of the subtype it accepts? If you want a `ValueWriter` to accept any type of `Value`, then there is no need for it to be generic.

Comment: @kaya3 - What I'm passing is by definition a subtype of `Value`, shouldn't that be enough?

Comment: A cat is a kind of animal and so is a dog. A `ValueWriter<Dog>` need not accept anything that isn't a dog. So what happens when you try to give it a cat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write:

```java
ValueWriter<? extends Value> valueWriter = writer.getValue();
```

`valueWriter` may be a type `ValueWriter<A>` where `A` extends `Value`.

Then `valueWriter.write` expect something of type `A`... and you give `v` of type `Value`. The compiler can't assure `v` is a type `A` (depending of the actual `valueWriter` type).

You should rewrite the program using something like:

```java
ValueWriter<A> valueWriter = writer.getValue();
```

Where `A` extends `Value`, and set `A`as the type of `v`. `A` should be introduced somewhere by the program.